# Calling removeChild() or removeAllChildren() does not immediately redraw the parent without the child?

Tags: removechild, addchild, skemitternode

**Calling removeChild() or removeAllChildren() does not immediately redraw the parent without the child?**

I call the following in my GameScene within its `didBegin` function when two bodies collide:

```
    func markStake(theUStake: SKSpriteNode) {
        
        let particleName = "smokeParticle.sks"
        
        if let emitter = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: particleName) {
            emitter.position = theUStake.position
            theUStake.addChild(emitter)
        }
                
    }   // markStake
```

Later I call the following in my GameViewController when I start the Game over:

```
    func initAllStakes() {
         
       for theUStake in UStakes {
            theUStake.removeAllChildren()
        }
        
    }   // initAllStakes
```

`markStake` works with the specified collision.

**But** calling `initAllStakes()` [as shown above] does not redraw the parent `UStake`. **Only if I add code** to redraw the `UStakes` **within `initAllStakes()`** do the `particle` children disappear.

1. Note that **UStakes** is a global in my `AppDelegate`:

`var UStakes: [SKSpriteNode] = [myU1, myU2, myU3, myU4, myU5]`

2. and that elsewhere, for example:

`myU2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: U2Img)`

Any ideas would be appreciated.